# search for folder wildcard and open folder

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble trying to accomplish a search for a folder with a wildcard within a directory.

The folder will look sort of like this: [2008][560909][Market Change] or [year][number][name]

Thus far this is what I have:

```
Function searching()

Dim choice, input
Dim strPatheServices

strPatheServices = "s:\dirr\subdirr\"
ending = true

choice = InputBox("Please choose: c for number, y for year created, n for name") 

If choice = "c" Then 
    MsgBox ("You entered: " & choice)
    input = InputBox("Please input a number:") 
    System.IO.Directory.Exists(strPatheServices\input)

ElseIf choice = "y" Then
    MsgBox ("You entered: " & choice)
    input = InputBox("Please input a year:") 
    System.IO.Directory.Exists(strPatheServices\input)

ElseIf choice = "n" Then
    MsgBox ("You entered: " & choice)
    input = InputBox("Please input a number:") 
    System.IO.Directory.Exists(strPatheServices\input)
End If

MsgBox "Done",,"Completed"

End Function
```

I am uncertain where to go from this other than add the wild card to the exist so like:

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists(strPatheServices\input + "*")
```

Please help I am so confused...

Comment: a terminal app redone with windows is not a terribly pleasant beast to use.

Comment: Also, the `&` operator is for string concatenation in VB.Net.  The `+` operator can produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath, wildcardPattern)` and see if the returned array contains more than zero elements.